# Use fallbacks pointing to another value within same row in Java enum

Tags: java, enums

I have a datastructure, for instance:

```
col1  col2  col3
 A     B     A
 C     D     E
 F     G     F
 H     H     H
```

Sometimes the values in a single row contain duplicates, which are fallbacks that point to other values within the same row.

I was wondering, if there is an elegant way to solve this with an enumeration in Java?

That is what I don't want to do:

```
public class MyClass {
    private enum MyEnum {
        ROW1("A", "B", "A"),
        ROW2("C", "D", "E"),
        ROW3("F", "G", "F"),
        ROW4("H", "H", "H");
        
        private final String col1;
        private final String col2;
        private final String col3;

        MyEnum(String col1, String col2, String col3) {
            this.col1=col1;
            this.col2=col2;
            this.col3=col3;
          }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ROW1.col3);
    }
}
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private enum MyEnum {
        ROW1("A", "B", equalsCol1()),
        ROW2("C", "D", "E"),
        ROW3(equalsCol3(), "G", "F"),
        ROW4(equalsCol2(), "H", equalsCol2());
        
        private final String col1;
        private final String col2;
        private final String col3;

        MyEnum(String col1, String col2, String col3) {
            this.col1=col1;
            this.col2=col2;
            this.col3=col3;
          }
          
        private static String equalsCol1() {
            return this.col1;
        }
        private static String equalsCol2() {
            return this.col2;
        }
        private static String equalsCol3() {
            return this.col3;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ROW1.col3);
    }
}
```

which will obviously result in:

```
/MyClass.java:19: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            return this.col1;
                   ^
/MyClass.java:22: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            return this.col2;
                   ^
/MyClass.java:25: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            return this.col3;
                   ^
3 errors
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve via the second approach.  Assuming it worked - how is it 'better' than the former version?

Comment: Maybe use one enum for columns and one enum for rows which does the combination of columns?

Comment: When you read the code, it's clear which one is set/which one belongs to which column and which one uses a fallback. Furthermore, assuming you have more values in this enum and one value changes, you just have to change it in one location instead of multiple.

Comment: And I always thought a minimal example with abstract data is the best you can do here... I guess it just does not work as I wished.

Comment: my idea on [IDEone](https://ideone.com/n6WCz7) {not sure if I like it or not...}

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for. But indeed, not sure if I like it or not, too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution provided by [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
 
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    private static final String COL1 = new String("COL1");
    private static final String COL2 = new String("COL2");
    private static final String COL3 = new String("COL3");
 
    private enum MyEnum {
        ROW1("A", "B", COL1),
        ROW2("C", "D", "E"),
        ROW3(COL3, "G", "F"),
        ROW4(COL2, "H", COL2);
 
        private final String col1;
        private final String col2;
        private final String col3;
 
        MyEnum(String col1, String col2, String col3) {
            this.col1=subs(col1, col1, col2, col3);
            this.col2=subs(col2, col1, col2, col3);
            this.col3=subs(col3, col1, col2, col3);
        }
 
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return col1 + col2 + col3;
        }
 
        private static String subs(String v, String col1, String col2, String col3) {
            return v==COL1 ? col1 : v==COL2 ? col2 : v==COL3 ? col3: v;
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ROW1);
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ROW2);
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ROW3);
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ROW4);
    }
}
```